# Can't upload stickers to iTunes Connect

Tags: xcode, app-store-connect, imessage, imessage-extension

I created sticker pack for iMessages in Xcode 8 and I want them to appear in iMessage App Store.
I created new app in iTunes Connect but I can't send it to review because I can't select uploaded build.

I waited for few hours but still can't see my build. It also isn't listed in TestFlight section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go over to iTunes Connect > My Apps > the App > Activity > All Builds

Have a look if the build appears there in the Processing state:

[image]

The processing is a little bit random and it happened in the past that it can take up to 48hrs to get the build "processed". If it's not even appearing in there, make sure you archive and upload it correctly with Xcode or the Application Loader.

I've got this encouraging message today:

> "We are currently experiencing processing issues. Build processing may be delayed."